# laravel 5.0 Facebook login. get Locale data.

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, laravel-5

I can use the laravel 5.0, it has created the ability to login to facebook.
We were able to log in, because profile information remains the default,
We want to increase the acquired items can be.

In the standard, id, Nickname, Name, Email, Avatar, but is a token,

Gender, I am birthday, I want to get the name of the locale (the name of the language representation other than English).

AuthController.php

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialize::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $userData = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();

    $user = User::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $userData->getName(),
                'email'    => $userData->getEmail(),
        ]);

    Auth::login($user);
    $user->photo = $userData->getAvatar();
    $user->access_token = $userData->token;

    $user->confirm();
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

It can be seen more, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not directly possible with the socialite-plugin: https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php

This is the code of the Facebook-Provider-Class - as you can see, the retrieved fields are hardcoded into the class - maybe try subclassing the Facebook-Provider?

Comment: files under the vendor is I do not want to change.
Do not be able to register the override class the FacebookProvider.php?